# Cleanest way of working out next variable name based on sequential order?

Tags: php, variables, key, sequential

Hope my title explains it ok! Here's more detail:

I'm creating an array which stores keys & their values. Eg.

```
test1 = hello
test2 = world
test3 = foo
```

What is the cleanest way of working out what to call the next key? Let's say I will know the first part is 'test', but I don't know what the highest value number is. Obviously in this case I want it to be called 'test4'.

In the example below I want the next key to be 'test46', as it is the next highest value:

```
test6 = blah
test45 = boo
test23 = far
```

Comment: just make a small indexer function and use getIndex() which will generate the next index for your array and use it as a key for new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementation of [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251553/cleanest-way-of-working-out-next-variable-name-based-on-sequential-order/6251571#6251571) answer without using a loop:

```
$arr = array('test6', 'test45', 'test23');
$max = max(filter_var_array($arr, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

$newKey = 'test' . ++$max; // string(6) "test46"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/jRRsDRHk)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like you should be using an array with numerical indexes instead.

You could however use some code like this...

```
$arr = array('test6', 'test45', 'test23');
$max = 0;

foreach($arr as $value) {
    $number = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $max = max($max, $number);
}

$newKey = 'test' . ++$max; // string(6) "test46"
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/IEy5f1UV).

Answer (score 1):

This data structure would be better stored as an array.

```
$test = array();
$test[] = 'hello';
$test[] = 'world';
$test[] = 'foo';
```

You then don't need to know the highest number to add a new item, just use the empty brackets syntax (shown above) to add an item to the end of the array.

You then have access to a wealth of array functions that PHP gives you to work with your data: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

When you want to get item 43 from the array, use:

```
echo $test[42];
```

Arrays are counted from 0 rather than 1, so item 43 will have an index of 42.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using that for? If numbering the array is a must-have, just use a simple numerical indexed array instead, and simply prepend the key with "test" if you need it to show up as "test1":

```
<?php

$array = array(
    6 => 'blah',
    45 => 'boo',
    23 => 'bar'
);

$array[] = 'new';

echo $array[46] . "\n"; // this is 'new'

foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    echo "test$key = $value<br />\n"; // test6 = blah
}
```